# Merge result of two queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two different queries:

```
SELECT 
    PB_BANK_CODE,
    PB_BANK_NAME
FROM GLAS_PDC_BANKS 
WHERE PB_COMP_CODE='1' 
AND PB_BANK_CODE='025' 
AND PB_BANK_CODE IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PC_BANK_FROM
    FROM GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES 
    WHERE PC_BANK_FROM ='025' 
    AND ISNULL(PC_DISCD,'X') != 'C'
    AND PC_DUE_DATETIME BETWEEN '05/05/2008' AND '05/06/2008'
)
```

and

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(PC_AMOUNT),0) 
FROM GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES 
WHERE PC_BANK_FROM ='025'
AND ISNULL(PC_DISCD,'X') != 'C'
AND PC_DUE_DATETIME BETWEEN '05/05/2008' AND '05/06/2008'
```

I'm trying to merge these two so that I can get `PB_BANK_CODE`, `PB_BANK_NAME`, and `ISNULL(SUM(PC_AMOUNT),0)` in a single dataset.

How can I merge these two queries in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: On which keys (other than CAPS) do you wish to JOIN these Tables/Output Results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it...

I think?

```
SELECT 
   PB_BANK_CODE,
   PB_BANK_NAME,
   ISNULL(SUM(PC_AMOUNT),0)
FROM GLAS_PDC_BANKS inner join GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES 
    on GLAS_PDC_BANKS.PB_BANK_CODE = GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES.PC_BANK_FROM
WHERE  PB_COMP_CODE='1' 
   AND PB_BANK_CODE='025' 
   AND ISNULL(PC_DISCD,'X') != 'C'
   AND PC_DUE_DATETIME BETWEEN '05/05/2008' AND '05/06/2008'
```

Comment: You are correct, that might work, I didn't know PB_BANK_CODE and PC_BANK_FROM had a relationship, but it sure seems that way since both have the same value of '025'.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make use of two technologies:

- SQL JOIN syntax (look it up in your database documentation, you didn't mention what database you're using)
- The lower case keys on your computer keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relationship between tables GLAS_PDC_BANKS and GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES then you can just join the two tables and make some small modifications to your query. Without knowing what type of relationship exists between these two tables, I cannot offer a more detailed answer.